# rewriting of this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is from [a webpage](https://ekja.org/journal/view.php?number=8734).

> **Total procedure duration and patient discomfort scores were not significant in the IT and CP groups.** However, the DSA was only seen
> in ultrasonographic images in the 7 patients of IT group. Unlike the
> onset time, which was faster in the IT group, the total duration of UN
> sensory block did not differ in the IT and CP groups (Table 2).

The 'Materials and Methods' part of the article says secondary outcomes of the study include duration of the procedure and patient discomfort score during the procedure, meaning it assessed statistical significance of the differences in those outcomes between the two groups(IT and CP groups).

So I think it is better to rewrite the sentence in bold as follows:

*The differences in total procedure duration and patient discomfort scores were not significant between the IT and CP groups.*

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your phrasing seems clearer, if that is the intended meaning.

The literal meaning of the emboldened phrase is that the "Total procedure duration score" was not significant in the CP group, and it was not significant in the IT group.  (and likewise for the patient discomfort score). There is no mention of any investigation of differences, so it should mean that the score was not significant compared to some nominal baseline.

The literal sense of the emboldened phrase doesn't mention any comparison between the CP and IT groups, only that the score is not significant in either.  Now, looking at the context and reading between the lines, I think your interpretation is probably correct, and the meaning is that there are no significant *differences*.  But that is not what the original author has written.

To understand this you'd probably need to know more about anesthesiology than that English grammar.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right.

To make the least changes to the sentence, you may wish to go with the following:

*Total procedure duration and patient discomfort scores were not **significantly different** in the IT and CP groups.*

Comment: Thank you very much.